# how to cast an observable collection to System.Data.Entity.DBSet type

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net, wpfdatagrid, ado.net-entity-data-model

Hi I am using an observable collection which I am displaying in the datagrid on the wpf screen.

I have linked this with ADO.NET Entity Data Model object. When I make any change to the data in the datagrid and do SaveChanges() this gets saved in the database. But if I add a row then that doesnt get added. Where am I going wrong.

The code used: 
Customer is a ADO.NET Entity Data Model object added for the table CustomerTable in SQL database.

```
Customer contextCust = new Customer();
var list = from e in contextCust.CustomerTable select e;
custCollection = new ObservableCollection<CustomerTable>(list);
```

Now when I change any data in the existing datagrid on the UI display I call the function:

```
contextCust.SaveChanges();
```

This works fine. But if I add a row on the UI, it gets added to the observable collection but how do I push this to the contextCust. Looks like only data changes are allowed by SaveChanges method but not adding of rows.

Is there a way I can cast observable collection to CustomerTable type and make contextCust consume the same. Kindly advise.

Thanks,
T

Comment: Why do you `RaisePropertyChanged("CustCollection")` if you are using an `ObservableCollection` anyway?

Comment: Yes RaiseProperty is not needed. Have corrected the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you add another row into your grid (assuming you are creating a `Customer`) you have to add it to `contextCust.CustomerTable` using the [DbSet.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg679587(v=vs.113).aspx) as well to track it for `SaveChanges`

Things added to your `ObservableCollection` will not be added to this `DbSet` as they are not connected/synced magically.

Comment: Hi but how do I know which row to be added from the collection. Is there no way to cast the collection object to contextCust in one line so that contextCust gets updated and then SaveChanges() will work ?

Comment: not that I know of  - you can subscribe to your own `ObservableCollection` and see when things get added if you like